# Translating from SQL enquiry to HQL enquiry problem

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I'm a hibernate user for only a few days and I came across a certain problem.

I can't work-out how to translate this SQL query into HQL:

```
SELECT name, street, city, description
    , (SELECT AVG(rate) 
      FROM user_restaurant_rating 
      WHERE user_restaurant_rating.restaurant_id = restaurants.id) AS rate 
FROM restaurants 
ORDER BY rate DESC 
LIMIT 0,3
```

I've read few tutorials, but haven't found how to translate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what sort of mapping you have created. Which table represented by which model class?

Answer (score 1):

[The Hibernate reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries) indicates that subselects in the select clause are supported. You should thus be able to write

```
select r.name, r.street, r.city, r.description, (select avg(ur.rate) from UserRestaurantRating ur where ur.restaurant.id = r.id) rate from Restaurant r order by rate desc
```

Comment: I sitll get an error:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: rate near line 1, column 132 [select r.name, r.street, r.city, r.description, (select avg(ur.rate) from user_restaurant_rating ur where ur.restaurant_id = r.id) rate from restaurants r order by rate desc]

Comment: tried, now new error:

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: restaurants is not mapped [select r.name, r.street, r.city, r.description, (select avg(ur.rate) from user_restaurant_rating ur where ur.restaurant_id = r.id) as rate from restaurants r order by rate desc]

Comment: You must not use the name of the table (restaurants), but the name of the entity mapped to the table (which I assumed in my answer being "Restaurant"). What's the mapping of these tables?

Comment: well, I mapped entity Restaurant as restaurant. When changed restaurants to restaurant in query, eclipse dropped same mistake

Comment: If the class name is "Restaurant", you must use "Restaurant". Case is important. Hibernate queries use entities, not tables. Why don't you show us your classes and mappings?